# How to extract a first 3 numbers within a variable?

Tags: r, number-formatting

My numeric variable looks like this:

```
u$a <- c(1234, 1432, 1456, 13467)
```

How do I create a new variable `a1` which is the first three characters of the variable `a` such that it would look like this:

```
u$a1 <- c(123, 143, 145, 134)
```

Thank you.

Comment: use integer division `a%/%10`

Answer (score 4):

use integer division.

```
u$a1 <- u$a%/% 10^(nchar(u$a)-3)

u
#>       a  a1
#> 1  1234 123
#> 2  1432 143
#> 3  1456 145
#> 4 13467 134
```

Answer (score 3):

You could first convert it to a `character` and use `substr` to get the first until third character and convert it back to `numeric` like this:

```r
u$a1 <- as.numeric(substr(as.character(u$a), 1, 3))
u
#>       a  a1
#> 1  1234 123
#> 2  1432 143
#> 3  1456 145
#> 4 13467 134
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data used:

```
u <- data.frame(a = c(1234, 1432, 1456, 13467))
```

Comment: actually you don't need `as.character`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sub`

```
u$a1 <- as.numeric(sub("^(...).*", "\\1", u$a))
```